# I want to perform search operation for a specific user in mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

This is my mongo collection name **asset**

```
 {
        "_id" : ObjectId("60709bac78f45041425be756"),
        "objectState" : "CURRENT",
        "description" : "Surfboards shop test Campanizer",
        "assetName" : "Surfboards shop test Campanizer",
        "createdBy" : {
            "$ref" : "users",
            "$id" : ObjectId("5e842b93992e8777e733f10f")
        },
        "company" : {
            "$ref" : "users",
            "$id" : ObjectId("60709ab978f45041425be752")
        },
    }
```

Now for searching suppose "test"
i am using this query

```
db.assets.find({
    $or : [ 
        {"assetName":  { $regex:"test", $options:'i' }},
        {"description":{$regex:"test",$options:'i'}}
       ],
})
```

and getting 10 results
in this 10 results 5 belongs to one company and 5 belongs to other
now i want to search this string "test" with object of a company
Find Asset with text "test" and company

"company" : {
"$ref" : "users",
"$id" : ObjectId("60709ab978f45041425be752")
},

What will be the mongo query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/b7NVBN6girr

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

```
db.collection.find({
  "company": {
    "$ref": "users",
    "$id": ObjectId("60709ab978f45041425be753")
  },
  $or : [ 
    {"assetName":  { $regex:"test", $options:'i' }},
    {"description":{$regex:"test",$options:'i'}}
   ]
})
```

Comment: Do you know how i convert this query to spring boot repository

Comment: @chaitanyagupta I don't have an idea on that, https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.query will help you.